# GIT client for AIX 6.1+

Tags: git, ssh, aix

I've seen lot of support for Linux and many other *NIX versions, but couldn't find an git RPM for AIX 6.1+

**Our Scenario**

- The GIT server/repository is hosted in a Linux Server
- Specific Application source code is present in AIX machine.
- We can ssh from AIX machine to GIT server

Is there anyway, we can do git commands without installing GIT at AIX machine?

Comment: why dont you just compile git from source? it's really straighforward, usually...

Comment: It seems you're trying to use Git for deployment, but why? Just `git archive` the version you want on the Git server and then `scp` it to your AIX application server, unwrap and deploy.

Comment: @kostix, Unfortunately we don't have any servers to host other than AIX boxes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether you want to move code in both directions (from AIX to repo and vice versa), but either way you have a few options:

1. Setup a rsync server, either on the repo server or one of your file servers, do a git checkout of the code and then setup rsync to share the checkout directory. This would allow you to simply do a git pull on the rsync server when you need to update the code on the AIX server. You can then simply setup a cronjob on the AIX to rsync the code across when changes are needed. My servers have a cronjob which uses rsync to pull changes across once an hour.
2. Simply install git on the AIX server. You can then do a simple git pull on the AIX server directly. You can find the git packages [on the Perzl package site](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.ListOfPackages)
3. You can setup an NFS or SAMBA server to do the same, but this is much more of a hassle imo.

On Linux or BSD I would usually agree with Nevik Rehnel's comment, but in my experience it's usually not that easy to compile from source on AIX :P I've had quite a few problems compiling from source, but luckily you can usually find packages for most things (especially the GNU build chain). If anyone wants to try to find a package instead of compiling from source, or if they are looking for GCC packages (since xlC is a paid product) you can look on the above mentioned perzl.org site or [on the IBM linux toolbox site](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html). The alternative site's packaes

Comment: (Step 2). As mentioned in my post our AIX is 6.1.x but the link provided only has AIX5.x version

Comment: The package is tagged for AIX 5.1 but will work on AIX 6.1 and AIX 7.1 as long as you install all the pre-reqs. On my side I installed it on AIX 7.1 TL2 without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly in the same problem and studying at the moment a solution based in the shell version of jgit (the one they call self-contained command line executable in their download page).

https://eclipse.org/jgit/

It did not exactly work as is.  In order to make it work, you need to separe the binary part of the .sh into a jar, and then inform its path into the JGIT_CLASSPATH env variable.  With these modifications, I have been able to clone a repository hosted into a remote gitlab server... working right now in my SSH authentication and pushing back changes :)

Comment: However I have found some problems to use it in a practical manner... complex commands that I need, such as archive or cat-file work in a different manner or don't work at all.  Looking for a way to compile it right now :(

Comment: We have finally succeeded in installing the solution provided by www.perlz.org, specifically the one compiled for AIX 7.1 in ftp://www.oss4aix.org/latest/aix71/  :D